# Can I auto-publish articles with future timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to add articles (data) in mysql/php but make them
auto-publish during the day when I´m not available.

So lets say, if I have a news site but I´ll be busy tomorrow the whole day so I could pre-write articles the day before with timestamp and they would appear when I want

Is this possible?

How would the script be like:

```
SELECT FROM articles WHEN TIME is 2011-12-01 12:15
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE timestamp <= NOW()
```

Comment: Well... since this is only a simple example, you'll have to give me a little more information to work with.

Comment: give me a few sec (hours) to double-check it - otherwise I´ll post the code

Answer (score 0):

Though I never worked with them to me the easiest solutions seems to be [Cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) combined with an extra waiting table and a script linking both.

You pre-write your article and store them in table together with the time stamp you want to publish them.
Your cron will invoke a script every 2,3, 5 hours (twice a day, whatever).

This script checks the time stamps in the table against the actual time and if it is about time to realise the article it will do so (or hand the information to the realise script).